# Some problems with interactive map on Jupyter

Tags: python, json, geopandas

I'm working to an interactive map following this [Guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-complete-guide-to-an-interactive-geographical-map-using-python-f4c5197e23e0)

I don't know why, but I only receive this message:

```
 BokehJS 2.3.2 successfully loaded.
```

Witouth any map generated. Why ?

I attach full code used on jupyter (created a new environment on conda to install geopandas and bokeh)

```
import geopandas as gpd

#Read shapefile using Geopandas
gdf = (gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\gpont\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\data\Map\map1\ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp"))[['ADMIN', 'ADM0_A3', 'geometry']]

#Rename columns.
gdf.columns = ['country', 'country_code', 'geometry']
gdf.head()

print(gdf.head())

print(gdf[gdf['country'] == 'Antarctica'])
#Drop row corresponding to 'Antarctica'
gdf = gdf.drop(gdf.index[159])

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\gpont\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\data\Map\databaseCDP0.csv')

import json

#Read data to json.
df_json = json.loads(df.to_json())

#Convert to String like object.
json_data = json.dumps(df_json)

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar
from bokeh.palettes import brewer

#Input GeoJSON source that contains features for plotting.
geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data)
#Define a sequential multi-hue color palette.
palette = brewer['YlGnBu'][8]
#Reverse color order so that dark blue is highest obesity.
palette = palette[::-1]
#Instantiate LinearColorMapper that linearly maps numbers in a range, into a sequence of colors.
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palette, low = 0, high = 40)
#Define custom tick labels for color bar.
tick_labels = {'0': '0%', '5': '5%', '10':'10%', '15':'15%', '20':'20%', '25':'25%', '30':'30%','35':'35%', '40': '>40%'}
#Create color bar.
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=8,width = 500, height = 20,
border_line_color=None,location = (0,0), orientation = 'horizontal', major_label_overrides = tick_labels)
#Create figure object.
p = figure(title = 'CDP_test', plot_height = 600 , plot_width = 950, toolbar_location = None)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
#Add patch renderer to figure.
p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource,fill_color = {'field' :'median_rating', 'transform' : color_mapper},
          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)
#Specify figure layout.
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')
#Display figure inline in Jupyter Notebook.
output_notebook()
#Display figure.
show(p)
```

Is there a probably error on line import json to read data? If yes, how can solve? Can't install Json on jupyter

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - json

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to
```